# Mean-center when the means and raw scores are in different DFs

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

DF1 has dim_scores for each user_id, dim_id and response_id

```
DF1 <- data.frame(user_id=c(rep(1,7),rep(2,6)),
              dim_id=c(1:4,1,4,2,1:4,2,4),
              response_id=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,2),3,rep(4,4),rep(5,2)),
              dim_score=c(56, 94, 17, 56, 54, 44, 90, 55, 32, 44, 32,36,22)
              )
   user_id dim_id response_id dim_score
1        1      1           1        56
2        1      2           1        94
3        1      3           1        17
4        1      4           1        56
5        1      1           2        54
6        1      4           2        44
7        1      2           3        90
8        2      1           4        55
9        2      2           4        32
10       2      3           4        44
11       2      4           4        32
12       2      2           5        36
13       2      4           5        22
```

DF2 has the means for each user_id:s dim_id, where the means derive from more scores than those in DF1.

```
DF2 <- data.frame(user_id=rep(1:2, each =4),
              dim_id=rep(1:4,2),
              dim_user_mean=c(55,87,27,50,60,34,60,27))
  user_id dim_id dim_user_mean
1       1      1            55
2       1      2            87
3       1      3            27
4       1      4            50
5       2      1            60
6       2      2            34
7       2      3            60
8       2      4            27
```

Whenever user_id AND dim_id match in DF1 and DF2, I want to subtract the dim_user_mean from the dim_score (i.e., mean centering) such that

```
DF_desired<-data.frame(user_id=c(rep(1,7),rep(2,6)),
                   dim_id=c(1:4,1,4,2,1:4,2,4),
                   response_id=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,2),3,rep(4,4),rep(5,2)),
                   dim_score_mean_centered=c(1, 7, -10, 6, -1, -6, 3, -5, -2, -16, 5, 2, -5)
                   )


   user_id dim_id response_id dim_score_mean_centered
1        1      1           1                       1
2        1      2           1                       7
3        1      3           1                     -10
4        1      4           1                       6
5        1      1           2                      -1
6        1      4           2                      -6
7        1      2           3                       3
8        2      1           4                      -5
9        2      2           4                      -2
10       2      3           4                     -16
11       2      4           4                       5
12       2      2           5                       2
13       2      4           5                      -5
```

Since the number of dim_scores per response_id differs it is not working to do

```
DF1$dim_score-rep(DF2$dim_user_mean, 4)
```

Would need something like

```
dim_score_mean_centered<-ifelse(DF1$user_id == DF2$user_id & DF1$dim_id == DF2$dim_id, 
                                DF1$dim_score - DF2$dim_user_mean, 
                                DF1$dim_score)
```

dim=dimension

Comment: First merge your two data.frames into one with `merge()` or `dplry::inner_join`, then you can more easily subtract the mean totals since they will be an additional column for each row.

Comment: As suggested above, try this with `dplyr` library: `inner_join(DF1, DF2) %>% mutate(centered_score = dim_score - dim_user_mean)`